# why wont php show more data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to grab the first 3 title names of my search results to display somewhere else and when i use

```
$rows[0]['title']
```

It works fine and shows the first title, or so its looks to be anyway but when i use

```
$rows[1]['title'] or $rows[2]['title']
```

It gives me the same results that this gives me

```
$rows[0]['title']
```

I have tried flipping everything around and doing all I can think of to grab the first 3 title names. anyone have any ideas?

Another thing to note is when I use

```
$rows['title']
```

I get no result at all.

EDIT:

Here is what is above the data i am trying to get.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
//$rows[$row['id']] = $row;
$rows[] = $row;
}
  foreach ($rows as $c => $row) {

}
```

Comment: We need more of your code to answer this. What *is* `$rows` exactly?

Comment: `$rows[1]['title'] or $rows[2]['title']`?  Do you know what `or` does?

Comment: What do you get when you do `print_r($rows)`?

Comment: How exactly do you want the first three titles outputted?  Separated by `<br />`?  In `<h2>` tags?

Comment: @deceze, I think the array fetched from a MySQL resource after performing a query. But what chris has posted here is not the source of the problem, the problem is in the code that fetched this array. I would suggest performing the SQL query via PHPMyAdmin first to ensure that the query itself isn't a problem, and then working to debug the remaining code from there.

Comment: when I print $rows I get all the data available. every result title, body etc.

Comment: I think seeing the actual SQL query might be of benefit here, and do as @LostInTheCode states and run the query elsewhere to check the results first, make sure it works as you expect.

Comment: i think u should access using $row instead of $rows

Comment: I dont care how they are outputted i just need them any way i can ge them

Comment: what makes this hard is im running sphinx and grabbing from mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  print_r($row);
  print("<br>");
}
```

So, if you have the following `$rows`:

```
[
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['d', 'e', 'f']
]
```

The code above would show you output similar to

```
array(
  [0] => 'a',
  [1] => 'b',
  [2] => 'c'
);
```

for the first `$row` in `$rows`. That is `$rows[0][0] = 'a'` or, in the `foreach` loop, `$row[0] = 'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

to

```
$rows[] .= $row;
```

Comment: The notation `$rows[] = $row` in PHP means to append a new element to the end of the array named `$rows`.